# Show dynamic value in dropdown in otrs

Tags: drop-down-menu, otrs

I have 2 dynamic field which are drop-down. Now I would like to show ones drop down's value based on another dropdown. 
For example, I have two dropdown called State and City.Now If I select Illinois state then in another dropdown it should show this state 's cities. So how to define this kind of relationship in otrs

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use javascript!
Every input in otrs layout have Ids and you can listen to events on those drop-downs, and do what you want.
You can add javascript code to your Output files (.tt files) in directory Kernel/Output/HTML/Standard of otrs.

```
[% WRAPPER JSOnDocumentComplete %]
<script type="text/javascript">

//your javascripts code goes here

</script>
[% END %]
```